# Tocar na foto e abrir a galeria e camera

Tags: android

Tenho uma tela de cadastro onde tem uma foto padrão de um usuário. Gostaria de colocar as duas opções. De quando o usuário tocar na foto abrir uma opção para ele pegar uma foto da galera e substitui a atual e ainda uma opção se ele quiser tirar uma foto na hora. Não sei se é muito complicado. Já pesquisei aqui no fórum e em outros site e achei somente para tirar a foto.

Comment: Qual a ação do usuário que vai disparar o evento de abrir câmera ?

Comment: isso aqui vai te ajudar.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309190/android-pick-images-from-gallery

Answer (score 6):

### Camera

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
```

### Galeria

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecione uma imagem"), 2);
```

### Tratamento da escolha

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
     //imagem veio da galeria
     Uri uriImagemGaleria = data.getData();
     String caminho = "";
     String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
     Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null,   null);
     if( cursor != null ){
          int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
          cursor.moveToFirst();
          return cursor.getString(column_index);
     }
     caminho = uri.getPath();
     caminho = getPath(uriImagemGaleria);
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(caminho);
     iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  }
  else if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
     //imagem veio da camera
     Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
     Bitmap imagem = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
     iv.setImageBitmap(imagem);
  }
}
```